# How is it possible to install openssl and curl extension for PHP8 on mac?

Tags: php, macos, php-curl, pecl, php-openssl

I installed PHP 8 with:

```
brew install php
```

Then I edited `php.ini` to enable curl and openssl:

```
extension=curl
extension=openssl
```

I use the default extension dir

```
extension_dir = "/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829"
```

I get this error (and the same for curl):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl' (no such file)), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl' (no such file)), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/openssl.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to install it with:

```
pecl install openssl
```

But I got:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/openssl"
install failed
```

The `/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829` directory is empty. I'm not sure where the extensions are located

Comment: Did you check whether openssl was probably already enabled before activating it? It's a core extension, not a PECL package